# Sort bibliographic entries by order of appearance of citation call-outs in document

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, natbib, apa-style, sorting

I would like to cite using

```
\bibliographystyle{apa}
```

and sort the cites in the same order they were called in the document.

I'm using

```
\usepackage[super,square,sort&compress]{natbib}
```

but it isn't sorting anything. To see where was the problem I tried changing the name of an author and it seemed that it was sorting the cites alphabetically according to the authors.

Comment: the `sort&compress`  option in natbib has to do with the way citations look in the text but not haw citations are sorted in the reference section.

Comment: the style `unsrtnat.bst` seems to do what you want but it does not follow the apa rules.

Comment: Thanks, I will consider it. Is there any way to solve it with apa rules?

Comment: I do not know. I never use the apa-like styles? Surely `biblatex` texperts will know more.

Comment: According to the meta data in [`apa.bst`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/contrib/misc/apa.bst) the style is from 1992 and therefore predates the 6th and 7th edition of the APA publication manual by at least one decade. So by today's standards `\bibliographystyle{apa}` is not guaranteed to provide APA style. If you want real APA style, use either `apacite` (BibTeX-based solution for 6th edition APA) or `biblatex-apa` (7th ed. APA style) or `biblatex-apa6` (6th edition APA style).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've discovered, the `apa` bibliography style is designed to sort entries alphabetically by authors' surnames. To achieve your formatting objective, I suggest you proceed as follows:

- Find the file `apa.bst` in your TeX distribution. Make a copy of this file and call the copy, say, `apa-nosort.bst`. (Do *not* edit an original file of the TeX distribution directly.)
- Open `apa-nosort.bst` in a text editor. The program you use to edit your tex files will do fine.
- Find the two instances of `OPEN` in the file. (In my copy of the file, they occur on lines 1050 and 1109.)
- Comment out or delete these lines.
- Save the file `apa-nosort.bst` either in the directory where your main tex file is located or in a directory that's searched by BibTeX. If you choose the latter option, be sure to also update the filename database of your TeX distribution suitably.
- In your main tex file, change the instruction `\bibliographystyle{apa}` to `\bibliographystyle{apa-nosort}` and perform a full recompile cycle: LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX *twice* more.

Happy BibTeXing!